# why does my HP deskjet ink advantage 2515 printer always show empty black ink levels despite new branded cartridges?

Tags: printer

I have an HP deskjet ink advantage 2515 printer which recently started printing blank pages (I was able to hear the motions of the printer). then suddenly i got empty ink level warning for black ink despite the fact that i had just then installed branded new cartridge. when i replaced it with a new one, i again got the same "empty black ink" warning while the tricolor ink levels are correct. 
What should i do? I have never used compatible ones, but just branded new cartridges so what could be the problem??

I would be greatly thankful if someone could please guide me on this. I have tried searching for solutions in internet but in vain..

Comment: I think it's pretty clear your printer is malfunctioning. Sounds like repair time and if you don't happen to be a printer technician then the repair shop just might be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use only HP ink, the chances are that your printer is needing repair in the sensor. But, because that can be expensive, if you have another 2515 available to use, swap out the ink with it. See if it sends the same message.

I used to sell HP printers and PCs. We had a flurry of people returning their HP Deskjets because the ink was not as good as we demonstrated, and they thought there was a sensor failure because it kept reporting out of ink. We either refunded or replaced the printer.

When the third one came in, we took time to research the problem. What we found was a common denominator. Every person who returned their printer bought new HP ink from a guy who was selling the cartridges below our wholesale costs.

Turns out, he was selling refilled cartridges as new. He was not charged with anything illegal because in his advertising, he had a tiny disclaimer. Once word got out about him, though, he went out of business.

That stuff is rare, now, though. So, if you can, run the test. If the other printer functions properly, most likely your printer has a bad sensor.